# How do I extract an element from an XML using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm using Selenium in Python to extract some information. At some point in my code, I have to access an XML URL and extract some data from it. However, when I try to find element by XPATH I get the following error `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:`
[This](https://www.spatialdata.gov.scot/geonetwork/srv/eng/xml.metadata.get?uuid=C0D1B950-5595-4DCD-9958-AD85571F30FA) is the URL in question:
Below is a snippet of the website:

```
<gmd:CI_Address>
<gmd:deliveryPoint>
<gco:CharacterString>Great Glen House, Leachkine Road</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:deliveryPoint>
<gmd:city>
<gco:CharacterString>Inverness</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:city>
<gmd:administrativeArea gco:nilReason="missing"/>
<gmd:postalCode>
<gco:CharacterString>IV3 8NW</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:postalCode>
<gmd:country>
<gco:CharacterString>United Kingdom</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:country>
<gmd:electronicMailAddress>
<gco:CharacterString>data_supply@nature.scot</gco:CharacterString>
</gmd:electronicMailAddress>
</gmd:CI_Address>
```

What I am trying to extract is the email address `data_supply@nature.scot` and here is my code:

```
driver.get(url)

email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="folder21"]/div[2]/div/span[2]')
```

I have used Developer tools to find the exact XPATH but I get the error mentioned above. Are you not able to use XPATH with XML? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was using the Developer Tools Xpath which is not exactly the best. The solution as I found out was as follows:

```
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//gmd:CI_ResponsibleParty/gmd:organisationName/gco:CharacterString').get_attribute('textContent')
```

The `textContent` was added because it returned a hidden text.
Hope this helps someone out there.